# How do you eat in Minecraft Pocket Edition 0.8.1?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I can cook and make cakes, but I still can't eat anything. How do I eat? I've looked for solutions everywhere and still have not found one that works.

Comment: Have you tried placing the cake like in PC Minecraft?

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear. Pocket edition. I place the cake but cannot eat it. I end up destroying it.

Answer (score 1):

Hold your finger on the food that's in your hand, and you must have missing hearts.

Answer (score 0):

Look up and press and h. Hold  your finger on screen

Answer (score 0):

You can only eat in mcpe when your health is low